# Minimum number of square Grids in a Rectangular Grid[JAVA]

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have been working on problem where i need to split a rectangular grid(M*N) on to minimum number of square grids and let me give an idea i had with an example..

let us consider 8*5 grid . The first maximum element we can takeout is 5*5 it will be left out with 3*5 later the maximum rectangle we can take out is 3*3 later it comes 2*3 which we can split to 2 1*1 grid i need a better algorithm with less time complexity as the above mentioned algorithm takes more time....thanks in regards..

here is visuals of given problem statement..
[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: this approach and logic sounds ok to me...to find the least number your squares, you WILL have to start with smallest dimension and repeat with the remaining dimension. what is your expectation here?

Comment: i need loop optimaization . the actual problem i had is i got 2 arrays  1 for m and 1 for n i need to use 4 loops is there any way for loop optimizations to improve my performance and help with pseudocode or code is appreciated

Comment: What is the end result here?

Comment: for above problem thats 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to finding the GCD(greatest common divisor) of two number.

This is how we visual an example to find GCD of pair (200x117)

[image]

So, what we can do is using the classic [Euclid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

if we have a rectangle size `(a,b) and a >= b` -> create `a/b` squares size `(b, b)` and solve the sub problem of rectangle size `(b, a % b)` and continue until we reach `(x, 0)`

Pseudo code

```
void gcd(int a, int b){
     if(b == 0)
        return;
     print a/b squares with size b x b;
     gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Time complexity should be O(log max(a,b))

So, for case (5,4) , first, we create an square (4,4) -> what left if (4,1) -> create 4 squares size (1,1) -> (1, 0) -> return;

Comment: There may be a case where b is power of a then we can divide that grid into that n powers of grid there we dont reach (1,1) right correct me if i am wrong.Thanks for your time

Comment: i got a case where a = 5 and b = 4 any possible explanation for the given constraints..

Comment: Hey i got a case where i need to go through i mean 6*3 while your algorithm returns 3 while required solution is 2 3*3 matrices how to proceed now

Comment: @SmashCode (6,3) -> create `6/3 = 2` square size ( 3,3) -> (3, 0) -> create no square -> return. You need to read my pseudocode one more time. Notice that I have specifically state that we need to create `a/b` squares.